# Combine two sources with different schemas in a single file keeping the schema per row in ADF Dataflow

Tags: azure-data-factory

i need to combine two sources into a single sink file with keeping the schema per row. Example:

**File 1**

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | D |

**File 2**

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| J | K |

**Output File**

*A, B, C, D*

*J, K*

- No need to header row.
- Each column separated by a comma
- Each row keep it's structure/schema:

Thanks for help

Comment: What are the file types of the input and output files? csv?

Comment: Hi Ray, the input files are CSV and the output files txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@[Kd85](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3797077/kd85) As per your comment, You want to combine 2 CSV files and store output in .txt file.

If you are using Binary dataset as Sink in copy activity, you can only copy from Binary dataset.

[image]

Please Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-binary

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a Union activity in your dataflow.
[image]
Choose **Output to single file** in the sink settings.
[image]
Result txt:

[image]

Comment: The problem is that i need a RowDelimiter right after the "K" value and not a ColumnDelimiter with null values:

A,B,C,D   \n
J,K           \n

Comment: I am not sure how you can keep the "structure" in this way. Following your example, if you have a third file: Column1 = X, Column3 = Y, is the expected output `X,,Y,` or `X,,Y`? I think you need to keep the empty columns to "maintain the structure"